# модуль Python для работы в Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

Привет!
Хочу автоматизировать отчет в экселе. Хочется понять, какой модуль может справиться с нужными задачами :
1. Сравнить ячейки в в разных столбцах (напр. B1 и E1), если значение в них одинаковое, скопировать значение из соседней ячейки в другую (напр. из D1 в C1). Всего ~100 строк.
2. Скопировать заданный диапазон ячеек на другой лист в определенное место.
3. (не обязательно) Возможность подкрашивать ячейки.

Подскажите, чем можно пользоваться?

Answer (score 2):

Для работы с файлами формата xls, можно использовать [xlrd и xlwt](http://www.python-excel.org/). Для xlsx больше подойдёт [openpyxl](http://www.python-excel.org/).

Comment: xlrd и xlwt хорошо работают с xls, т.к. разрабатывались под него. Совместимость с xlsx есть, но могут и вылезти какие-то недоработки (я сталкивался с тем, что xlrd не понимает форматирование ячейки, пишет что функция не реализована). Поэтому для xlsx лучше использовать например openpyxl.

Comment: @insolor доступный по той же ссылке.

Comment: Но в ответе про него ни слова. Я думаю, в любом случае стоит дополнить ответ.